# PostgreSQL pg_basebackup missing toc.dat header file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I'm using the following command to backup my database (PostgreSQL 11.8):

```
pg_basebackup -D "C:\\temp" -F tar -X f -z -P -U myUser
```

And the following to restore:

1. I manually unpack the base.tar.gz => base.tar
2. `pg_restore -h localhost -W -U myUser -c -C -d myDatabase -F tar -v "C:\\temp\\base.tar"`

This results in the following error:

> pg_restore: [tar archiver] could not find header for file "toc.dat" in tar archive

What am I doing wrong?
Also, I tried different versions of the restore (only data, etc.) but of course the missing header file issue persists.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use pg_basebackup and pg_restore together:

- pg_basebackup is a **physical** backup tool
- pg_restore can only be used with a **logical** backup created by pg_dump.

There is no single PostgreSQL command to restore a backup created with pg_basebackup.

To restore a physical backup see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-PITR-RECOVERY